# How to detect when the YouTube doesn't load?

Tags: html, iframe, youtube, loading

I have a web-page that allows the user to enter YouTube video URLs and display them in thumbnail previewers which do not auto-play them.  When the user enters the URLs:

1. some may be valid and load,
2. some are not valid and don't load,
3. some, while valid URLs aren't embeds with URLs similar to

   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NCZaq9pSBxQ and don't load, and
4. finally, while very rare, are valid, aren't embeds, but still load.

So, I don't want to prevent the user from entering any of these YouTube URLs, embed or not.  Instead, I want to detect when the YouTube video doesn't load.

Here is some of the HTML 'code' that I'm using that shows one YouTube that doesn't load and one that does:

```js
function update_ytplayer2( This ) {
 
 // validate the textarea's value -- omitted

  document.getElementById( 'ytplayer_2' ).src = This.value.trim();
}
```

```css
.webvideourlPreview {
    height: auto;
    width: 75px;
    max-height: 110px;
    margin-right: 3px;
}
textarea {
    width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<iframe id="ytplayer_0" class="webvideourlPreview" scrolling="no" 
    src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NCZaq9pSBxQ"
    source="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NCZaq9pSBxQ"
    video="true" youtube="true" style="display: block;"></iframe>

⁝<br />

<textarea onblur="update_ytplayer2( this );">https://www.youtube.com/embed/0376xWdwBBs</textarea><br />

⁝

<iframe id="ytplayer_2" class="webvideourlPreview" scrolling="no"
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/0376xWdwBBs"
    source="https://www.youtube.com/embed/0376xWdwBBs"
    video="true" youtube="true" embed="true"
    style="display: block;"></iframe>
```

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/howardb1/pen/eYZvQJM) that shows the second iframe like it does in my web-page. which uses the same code and css styles as used above.

Here is what I see in the Chrome Browser's Inspect Element panel:

```
⁝
 <!-- Non-Working YouTube Video -->
▼<iframe id="ytplayer_0" class="webvideourlPreview" scrolling="no"
         src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NCZaq9pSBxQ"
         source="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NCZaq9pSBxQ"
         video="true" youtube="true" style="">
 </iframe>
⁝
 <!-- Working YouTube Video -->
▼<iframe id="ytplayer_2" class="webvideourlPreview" scrolling="no"
          src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/0376xWdwBBs"
          source="https://www.youtube.com/embed/0376xWdwBBs"
         video="true" youtube="true" embed="true" style="display: block;">
    #document
    <!DOCUMENT html>
   ▶<html lang="en" dir="ltr" data-cast-api-enabled="true"
          wtx-context="AE89359A-CCF4-46DF-933F-36746B4B5815">
    </html>
  </iframe>
⁝
```

Both of the iframe tags are open, but I noticed that the non-working YouTube doesn't show anything between the open and close iframe tags, but the working YouTube does.

Is there some way that I can detect this in javaScript?

I saw that there was a .contentDocument property, but in Chrome this is always null, and there is a .contentWindow property, but both the non-working and working YouTube videos pretty much appear to show the same object/structure and so far I haven't found anything in the object that I can use to programmatically determine which video isn't working and which is.

I understand that there are two events that can be used, error and load, according to the information that I've found on these event because I'm not loading a file into the iframe, the events don't 'fire' whether the YouTube video loads or not.

I also saw somewhere in StackOverflow that the native size properties contain size of the small sad-face graphic, but I don't see how to get that information, especially since the .contentWindow doesn't appear, as far as I can tell, to these properties when I inspect these elements.  However, I'd rather not rely only on the size of the image alone to determine the failure of the load.

Thanks

Comment: where should user enter link? Which script loading that link in the iframe?

Comment: The user enters the YouTube video URL into a textarea, which when changed/blurs, causes an event handler function, not shown -- but very trivial, to execute and validate that the format of the textarea's value is a possible YouTube URL, and if it is then assign it to the one of the iframes' src property.  The user is expected to type in or paste in a YouTube video URL.

Comment: I updated the example so you can change the value of the second iframe's src property.

Comment: I added a link to a codepen version of the above code and css.

Comment: thanks, I will check it

Answer (score 0):

Actually YouTube doesn't allow 3rd parties to embed their site directly.
That is why using links like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NCZaq9pSBxQ or https://youtu.be/NCZaq9pSBxQ will raise `Refused to display 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NCZaq9pSBxQ' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.` warning in your console.

Fortunately Youtube offers "embed video" option, to allow us to embed videos. Using this feature I had written my code. Check out this snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .webvideourlPreview {
            height: auto;
            width: 75px;
            max-height: 110px;
            margin-right: 3px;
        }
        textarea {
            width: 400px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function update_ytplayer2( This ) {
            //capture trimmed value
            let val = This.value.trim();
            let embed_src;
            if(val.includes('watch?v='))
                embed_src = This.value.replace("watch?v=", "embed/");
            else if(val.includes('youtu.be'))
                embed_src = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/'
                            + val.split('/').pop();

            // validate the textarea's value -- omitted
            document.getElementById( 'ytplayer_2' ).src = embed_src;
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body on>
    <iframe id="ytplayer_0" class="webvideourlPreview" scrolling="no" 
    src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NCZaq9pSBxQ"
    source="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NCZaq9pSBxQ"
    video="true" youtube="true" style="display: block;"></iframe>

    ⁝<br />

    <textarea onblur="update_ytplayer2( this );">https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NCZaq9pSBxQ</textarea><br />

    ⁝

    <iframe id="ytplayer_2" class="webvideourlPreview"
    style="display: block;"></iframe>
  </body>
  </html>
```

In the snippet, inside function `update_ytplayer2` we using `val` variable to save trimmed value of our `<textarea>`. Next depending on the type of link, we may or may not altering it to get link in the form of `https://www.youtube.com/embed/[unique_identifier]` and save it into another variable `embed_src`.Finally, setting embed_src as our `<iframe>` source.

Function `update_ytplayer2` called each time user generate *blur* effect on `<textarea>` by moving focus away from it which in turn updates the video shown in `<iframe id="ytplayer_2">`.

**Note:** I had removed the HTML5 non-standard attributes from the `<iframe id="ytplayer_2">`.

Comment: Thank you, good information.  However, my users may or may not know that they should only use the embed format and type in or paste in a non-embed format URL, in which case I want to show the sad-face image that YouTube puts in the iframe, as I've already shown, but I also want to detect the the video didn't load so my web-page doesn't try to do more than show the sad-face image.  Those non-standard attributes were for my application, but not used for displaying the video, but that you removed them in your example isn't a problem.

Comment: Now they can insert  any of the watch, embed and share(youtu.be) formats. Doesn't it solved your problem?

Comment: I ran into some problems in the past where old YouTube non-embed videos didn't play when their URLs were changed as you show.  I used to show these in an iframe, but when that stopped working, I started using an older version of jwPlayer to play these videos, and surprisingly some of them still play.  Now, because this doesn't work for newer videos, I just go with the iframe player    and show the sad-face when the YouTube video doesn't load.  However, I want to update those non-standard attributes so that the jwPlayer can take over, except I need to detect that the YouTube video didn't load.

Comment: In other words, for those users who know their videos used to work, I can still make them work, sometimes.  If jwPlayer, the old version, doesn't work, the user sees that, and knows that they have to update the YouTube video to work properly as an embed, if they own the video.

Comment: I noticed same. When I opened your page on Chrome based browser `<iframe>` is blank. When I opened in Firefox, Youtube warning page pops up.

Comment: In Chrome, while using the Inspect Source panel, I see that the line that assigns the URL to the iframe shows a red-x circle, which when I float my mouse pointer over the circle, indicates that the video refused to load.  How can I catch this?  A simple Try-Catch block won't work because the assignment actually works.  From what I've read, the iframe's load and error don't execute for non-file assignments.

Comment: May be chrome has some internal programming of it. Because both are Google products. They surely put some internal logic to handle this case. After all Youtube is huge revenue collection site. Infact if we think of it as a search engine than it would be the 2nd biggest SE beating Yahoo, Bing and all

Comment: So, it would seem that between our combined knowledge, there isn't a way to reproduce what chrome is doing when it shows that a YouTube video refuses to be loaded into an iframe, and that the only other way that this could be done is to check the picture's content or width and height matches the sad-faced image, except I don't know how to get that information from the img tag inside of the iframe.